# Sudoku backtracking solver bug

Tags: python, debugging, backtracking, sudoku

Ok, I've been scratching my head over this for a few hours now..

My goal was to code a sudoku solver that uses the backtracking method and to show the progress of the algorithm using pygame. For this I have to keep track of the events, I did it by appending them to a list named `registre` as is shown in the code:

```
def solver(self):
    self.t1 = time.time()
    if self.t1-self.t0 > self.solve_time_max:
        sys.exit(1)
    for i in range(self.grid.shape[0]):
        for j in range(self.grid.shape[1]):
            if self.grid[i][j]==0:
                for n in range(1,10):        
                    self.registre.append([n,i,j])
                    if self.verify(n,i,j):
                        self.grid[i][j]=n
                        
                        self.solver()
                        if 0 not in self.grid:
                            break
                    self.registre.append([0,i,j])
                    self.grid[i][j]=0
                    
                return self.grid
```

I actually succeeded and everything goes fine for most of the runs. But sometimes, for some reason I couldn't identify, this happens :

```
    print(une_grille.grid0)
    print(une_grille.grid)
    print(une_grille.registre[:20])
```

```
   [[0 8 0 7 0 0 0 0 2]
    [5 0 0 0 0 9 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 1 0 0 6 0 0 0 0]
    [4 0 0 9 0 0 0 0 0]
    [0 0 9 0 8 0 0 0 4]
    [2 0 0 0 0 0 0 8 0]
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]]
   [[1 8 3 7 4 5 6 9 2]
    [5 2 4 6 1 9 3 7 8]
    [6 9 7 2 3 8 1 4 5]
    [3 5 2 8 7 1 4 6 9]
    [9 1 8 3 6 4 2 5 7]
    [4 7 6 9 5 2 8 1 3]
    [7 3 9 1 8 6 5 2 4]
    [2 4 1 5 9 3 7 8 6]
    [8 6 5 4 2 7 9 3 1]]
    [[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [2, 0, 1], [0, 0, 1], [3, 0, 1], [1, 0, 
    2], [0, 0, 2], [2, 0, 2], [0, 0, 2], [3, 0, 2], [0, 0, 2], [4, 0, 2], [0, 
    0, 2], [5, 0, 2], [1, 0, 3], [0, 0, 3], [2, 0, 3], [0, 0, 3], [3, 0, 3]]
```

What is printed is simply the initialized grid, the solved grid and the first 20 events in `self.registre`. For this run the displaying on pygame didn't work, some numbers overlap themselves and others are left blank. I am almost sure it's not a displaying problem since the displaying function uses the list `registre` and it works just fine for most of the other runs. Also I don't understand these events.

Complete script :

```
import numpy as np
import random as rd
import time
import sys

class Grid():

"""
une Docstring

"""
def __init__(self, nval=15, dim=(9,9), tries_max=1000, init_time_max=5e-3, solve_time_max = 1):
    self.nval = nval+1
    self.dim = dim 
    self.t0 = 0
    self.t1 = 0
    self.tries_max = tries_max
    self.k = 0
    self.init_time_max = init_time_max
    self.solve_time_max = solve_time_max
    self.registre = []
    
    self.grid =  self.create_grid()   
    self.smthg = 0
    
    
def create_grid(self):
    for tries in range(self.tries_max):
        self.k = 0
        if tries == self.tries_max -1:
            print(f"Tried {self.tries_max} times, I have failed")
            sys.exit(1)
        self.grid0 = np.zeros([self.dim[0],self.dim[1]], dtype=int)
        try:
            self.grid0 = self.initialize_board()
        except SystemExit:
            print(f"TRY #{tries}: Spent too much time initializing board. Re-trying.")
            continue
        self.grid = np.copy(self.grid0)
        try:
            self.t0 = time.time()
            self.grid = self.solver()
            if 0 not in self.grid:
                print(f"Found grid with solution after n = {tries+1} tries!")
                return self.grid
            else:
                print(f"TRY #{tries} converged to null solution")
                continue
        except SystemExit:
            print(f"TRY #{tries} too much time spent trying to solve current grid, continuing")
            continue
    print("Maximum tries reached")
    
def initialize_board(self):
    for i in range(self.nval):
        rx = rd.randint(0, self.grid0.shape[0]-1)
        ry = rd.randint(0, self.grid0.shape[1]-1)
        cx = int(rx/3)
        cy = int(ry/3)
        time0 = time.time()
        while(self.grid0[rx][ry]==0):
            if time.time()-time0 > self.init_time_max:
                sys.exit(1)
            r = rd.randint(1, 9)
            if((r in self.grid0[rx,:]) or (r in self.grid0[:,ry]) or (r in self.grid0[3*cx:3*cx+3,3*cy:3*cy+3])):
                continue
            else:
                self.grid0[rx][ry] = r
    return self.grid0
        





def solver(self):
    self.t1 = time.time()
    if self.t1-self.t0 > self.solve_time_max:
        sys.exit(1)
    for i in range(self.grid.shape[0]):
        for j in range(self.grid.shape[1]):
            if self.grid[i][j]==0:
                for n in range(1,10):        
                    self.registre.append([n,i,j])
                    if self.verify(n,i,j):
                        self.grid[i][j]=n
                        
                        self.solver()
                        if 0 not in self.grid:
                            break
                    self.registre.append([0,i,j])
                    self.grid[i][j]=0
                    
                return self.grid
    
def verify(self, number, x, y):
    cx = int(x/3)
    cy = int(y/3)
    if((number in self.grid[x,:]) or (number in self.grid[:,y]) or (number in self.grid[3*cx:3*cx+3,3*cy:3*cy+3])):
        return False
    return True
    

game = Grid(nval = 35)
print(game.grid)
print(game.grid0)
print(game.registre[:20])
```

Another instance of the issue :

```
[[1 2 3 9 5 7 6 4 8]
 [5 8 4 6 2 1 9 7 3]
 [7 9 6 8 4 3 1 5 2]
 [6 7 2 5 1 4 3 8 9]
 [3 4 9 7 8 6 5 2 1]
 [8 5 1 3 9 2 7 6 4]
 [2 1 5 4 6 9 8 3 7]
 [4 6 7 1 3 8 2 9 5]
 [9 3 8 2 7 5 4 1 6]]
[[0 0 0 9 0 7 6 0 0]
 [0 0 0 6 0 0 0 0 3]
 [0 0 0 8 4 3 1 5 2]
 [6 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 4 9 0 0 6 5 2 0]
 [0 5 1 0 9 0 7 0 0]
 [0 1 5 0 0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 7 0 0 0 0 0 5]
 [9 0 0 2 0 0 0 1 0]]
[[1, 0, 2], [0, 0, 2], [2, 0, 2], [0, 0, 2], [3, 0, 2], [1, 0, 3], [0, 0, 3], [2, 0, 3], [0, 0, 3], [3, 0, 3], [0, 0, 3], [4, 0, 3], [1, 0, 4], [0, 0, 4], [2, 0, 4], [0, 0, 4], [3, 0, 4], [0, 0, 4], [4, 0, 4], [0, 0, 4]]
```

I would really appreciate it if you could help me with this.

Comment: Please do not post text as image.

Comment: Yes I am sorry, but I can't directly post pictures since I don't have enough reputation yet. I'll edit and put the code at least.

Comment: Please also add the output you get, and the code that produces that output (with `print`) as the code you have provided does not output anything.

Comment: Ok here it is, sorry again.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this output. For the example grid (that has a non-zero value at [0,1]), the registre output doesn't look like that. The second entry in that registre is in contradiction to the input grid, and when I try to make it run, that registre starts with `[[1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 2],...`. Please provide information to allow to reproduce whatever the problem is. Just provide code that we can run. Now you leave out essential code...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers, I just edited adding the whole script. Keep in mind that you have to run it multiple time for the issue to occur.

Comment: I ran it a few times and I don't see an issue with the output. I could not reproduce the inconsistency that I described in my previous comment, which apparently you get. Can you be very clear what exactly is the problem here?

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to move to chat, so I'll just put another example of the issue in the main question. I don't understand why the `registre` doesn't start with `[1,0,0]` since the (0,0) element is 0 and filling it with 1 is permitted ? Then it should be followed by `[1,0,1],[0,0,1],[2,0,1]` since putting one in (0,1) is not permitted because there is already a 1 in (0,0). Yet these elements are missing in `registre`.  I hope I was clear enough. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After you added the code that *repeats* the generation of grids, it becomes clear that you don't create a new instance of `Grid`, but mutate the existing one. In that process you should then take care to reset the state *completely*. You only do this partly, e.g. by resetting `t0`. But you don't reset `registre`, and so when you print the first 20 items, you are actually looking at the log of the first attempt, not the successful one.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I can see it clearly now.